# Incorrect sum of multiples for 3 and 5

Tags: c#

Trying to write code that calculates sum of multiples of 3 & 5 under a value entered by user.
The problem is the code is adding the common multiples twice which is giving incorrect answer at the end. How can I solve this?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String userenter;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter the value you want for the sum of multiples of 3 and 5 to be below of: ");
        userenter = Console.ReadLine();
        int n;
        int.TryParse(userenter, out n);

        int i, sum2=0;
        for (i = 1; i < n / 3.0; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "3*" + i + "=" + 3 * i);
            Console.WriteLine(sum2 += 3 * i);
        }


        for (i = 1; i < n / 5.0; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n"+"5*"+i+"="+5 * i);
            Console.WriteLine(sum2 += 5 * i);
        }


       //Console.WriteLine("The sum of multiples of 3 under "+"n "+ "is ");

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: He actually tried to write the code though, looks like he's asking for help.

Comment: What is the actual question - only add up the unique multiples of 3 + 5 *below* "N"? (or through "N")?

Comment: @chrfin No, it's not homework; it's a project euler problem: http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Comment: @Dennis_E - Regardless, it isn't against the rules to ask any form of homework question, its a programming question with a clear attempt from the OP

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're looping through n twice, thus any multiples of both 5 and 3 will be hit and added/printed twice.  Try just looping over n once:

```
int sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
        sum += i;
return sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
int upperBound = 1000;
var sum  = Enumerable.Range(1,upperBound)
                     .Where(x=>x%3==0 || x%5==0)
                     .Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimalist change would probably be changing:

```
for (i = 1; i < n / 5.0; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n"+"5*"+i+"="+5 * i);
    Console.WriteLine(sum2 += 5 * i);
}
```

into something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < n / 5.0; i++)
{
    if ((i * 5) % 3 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n"+"5*"+i+"="+5 * i);
        Console.WriteLine(sum2 += 5 * i);
    }
}
```

so as to not double-count mutiples of fifteen.

However, it's probably easier to do it with something that checks for either condition on all numbers in the range since the computer will probably finish this before you've fully taken your finger off the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```
sum = 0
for i in range 1..whatever:
    if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
        sum = sum + num
```

I've put that in as pseudo-code since the whole point of Euler is to figure out how to do it yourself, so you should do *some* of the work :-)

Just keep in mind that this sort of brute force approach may work for Euler #1 but it won't be much good for later problems.

---

For what it's worth, I recently wrote a blog article which gave an O(1) solution for this exact problem, but it's not scheduled to be published for quite a while.

It takes a bit of mathematical knowledge but, even with a limit of 10<sup>100</sup>, the Python code still runs in under half a second under CygWin, and possibly even faster under Linux "proper".

You'll have to wait for the actual article to get the math explained but the following teaser shows how it's done:

```
limit = 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10                 # 10^5      = 10^5
limit = limit * limit * limit * limit          # (10^5)^4  = 10^20
limit = limit * limit * limit * limit * limit  # (10^20)^5 = 10^100

sum = 0
fullGroups = int((limit - 1) / 15)
sum = fullGroups * (fullGroups - 1) * 105 / 2 + fullGroups * 60
for num in xrange(fullGroups * 15 + 1, limit):
    if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
        sum = sum + num
print sum
```

If enough people clamour for it (unlikely), I may reschedule to bring it forward.

---

Of course, there's a way to do this (for power-of-ten limits) without *any* calculations other than the ability to count up to small numbers.

Have a look at what you get for a limit of one thousand, ten thousand, a hundred thousand and so on and see if you can see the pattern :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use one loop and check if one of the conditions is met:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        sum += i;
}
```

or a "one-liner" using LINQ (but this will be slower, because of the enumerable created):

```
int sum = Enumerable.Range(1, n - 1).Sum(v => v % 3 == 0 || v % 5 == 0 ? v : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it: "The problem is the code is adding the common multiples twice". So, you have to remove them or simply not count them twice.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) sum += i;
}
```

There is a much better way though, but you should really find that out yourself (it's math)